# UWP Drag-And-Drop Grid visual displaced from mouse?

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop, uwp, uwp-xaml

I am currently working on a game for UWP and have hit a little snag. I have created a <strike>6x6</strike> 5x5 grid that I would like to drag around the screen, and I have the click, drag, and drop working correctly, however, <strike>the visual that is displayed is offset from the mouse (drag doesn't kick in when the mouse moves after a click, only after it moves off the boundary of the grid)</strike> the visual appears wherever the mouse began the drag.

I need to get the center point of the grid to be right underneath the mouse. I have tried adjusting the RenderTransformOrigin and RenderTransform.TransformPoint() properties, and also trying to trigger the DragStarting() even from the PointerMoved/PointerPressed events, but these have done nothing.

EDIT: Here is an [example project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ztygl9fhkn5mcqk/StackOverflow%20Debugging.zip?dl=0) that showcases the issue. Currently the default drag will make the visual of the grid remain underneath the mouse at the point that you began the drag. I would like to have it so that the mouse is always at the direct center of the grid. As I have stated above, I have tried all of the transformations in guides online, but most of the examples that I have found involve PictureBoxes which doesn't translate to grids.

Any help would be appreciated,
Thank you very much!

Comment: Could you share a [mcve]? Withou a sample, it's hard to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Yes, sorry. Later today I will make an edit and provide you with a small example of what is happening.

Comment: @ZORRO So for whatever reason my original issue just stopped occuring, but in making the example project I noticed another related issue. I have explained it up above with my edits. Thank you for taking the time to look at this.